# Split data into separate files unix

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have data in below format

```
 _id :  ANC,Name : TEST,actn : Testing,date : 2018-0208   |    _id :  ANC,Name : TEST,actn : Testing,date : 2018-0208
                                                          >    _id :  ANC,Name : TEST,actn : Testing,date : 2018-0209
 _id :  ANC,Name : TEST,actn : Testing,date : 2018-0210   <
```

I want to split data into separate files based following condition :--

```
anything before  | should go in file 1 and after | should go in file 2.
Anything after > should in file 2 
Anything before < should go in file 1
```

So at the end files would look like :--

`File1:--
  _id :  ANC,Name : TEST,actn : Testing,date : 2018-0208
_id :  ANC,Name : TEST,actn : Testing,date : 2018-0210
File2 
_id :  ANC,Name : TEST,actn : Testing,date : 2018-0208
_id :  ANC,Name : TEST,actn : Testing,date : 2018-0209`

I tried doing it using sed
 `sed 's/|.*//' test.txt`  but unfortunately I am not able to add all conditions so data is getting messed.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following simple `awk` may help you on same too.

```
awk -F'[|><]' '{gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")}$1{print $1 > "file1"} $2{print $2 > "file2"}'    Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using, `awk`, since you essentially have two columns (assuming no other`|,<,>`):

```
awk -F' *[<>|] *' '{if ( $1 != "" ) { print $1 > "file1"; }; if ( $2 != "") { print $2 > "file2" } }' inputfile
```

1. `-F` is setting the delimiter to one of the 3 special symbols, with any amount of apace after and before.
2. If the first column is not empty, print it to file 1.
3. If the second column is not empty, print it to file 2.

If you don't mind a few steps you can replace the delimiters with a single delimiter:

```
sed -i 's/[<>]/|/' input
```

and then just using `cut -d'|' -f1 > file1` would work. Same for file 2 - though you would have empty lines. Also you can use a bash loop and easily iterate line by line splitting the line n one of the delimiters, but I think `awk` here is well suited.

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=2; i++) if ($i) print $i > "file"i }' \
       FS='[[:space:]][[:space:]]+[|<>][[:space:]][[:space:]]+' file
```

Viewing results:

```
$ head file[12]
==> file1 <==
_id :  ANC,Name : TEST,actn : Testing,date : 2018-0208
 _id :  ANC,Name : TEST,actn : Testing,date : 2018-0210

==> file2 <==
_id :  ANC,Name : TEST,actn : Testing,date : 2018-0208
_id :  ANC,Name : TEST,actn : Testing,date : 2018-0209
```